# Two-leg games in Elo rating for football teams

Tags: analysis, functions, inequality

Do you know Elo rating for association football? It is a numerical estimation of strength of football clubs using simple mathematical formula based  past results allowing predictions for the future.

> If two teams play each other, the resulting change in points of one team is calculated as follows:
>   $$ \Delta P = W \times \max (\sqrt{| G - G_{O}|}, 1) \times (R - \frac{1}{10^{\frac{-(P - P_{O} + V)}{400}} + 1})$$

where

$\Delta P$ : The point that the team gets after the match.

$W$ : Weight(significance) of the game. 0 for friendly matches, 20 for official matches, 40 for "big" games (such as World cup, ...)

$G$ : Number of goals scored in the game by our team.

$G_{O}$ : Number of goals scored in the game by the opponent.

$R$ : Result of the game. 1 for win, 0.5 for draw, 0 for defeat.

$P$ : Current point of our team, before the game.

$P_{O}$ : Current point of the opponent, before the game.

$V$ : Home advantage. 0 for neutral venue, 90 for domestic home game, -90 for domestic away game, 120 for international home game, -120 for international away game.

For example:

Real Sociedad (Spain) beat Real Madrid (Spain) 4-2 at their home. Before the game, the points of two teams were Real Sociedad 1752, Real Madrid 2081. 
After the game, Real Sociedad get $\displaystyle 20 \times \sqrt{2} \times (1 - \frac{1}{10^{\frac{-(1752+90-2081)}{400}} + 1}) = 22.5798$ points, Real Madrid lose $22.5798$ points. (As you notice, the rating is always zero-sum game)

Chelsea (England, 1950 pts) beats Schalke (Germany, 1773 pts) 5-0 at the away game. 
Chelsea get $18.7248$ points, Schalke lose $18.7248$ points.

Real Madrid (Spain, 2101 pts) beats Razgrad (Bulgaria, 1542 pts) 4-0 at their home. Real Madrid get $0.7869$ points, Razgrad lose $0.7869$ points.

The formula is generally considered reasonable when it comes to single-leg games. However, the problem arises on two-leg games (such as UEFA Champions League knockout tournament): A team winning its first leg by a high margin can afford to lose the second leg by a narrow margin. Consider this real example:

In 2013/14 UEFA Champions League quarterfinal game, Real Madrid (pts around 2050) beat Dortmund(pts around 1870) 3-0 at first-leg home game, and lost to Dortmund 0-2 at second-leg away game, but anyway qualified through semifinal with aggregate score 3-2.

If we apply the formula to each two of games individually, then Real Madrid get 5.18 points in the first leg, and lost 17.15 points in the second leg, resulting total loss of 12.03 points. This is NOT PLAUSIBLE, because the eventual winner of the two-leg game was Real Madrid anyway.

So, we have to apply the formula in different manner for 2nd-leg games in double-leg tournament matches.

What I think that the new revised formula must satisfy is:

> 1. What really matter is to qualify for the next round. Hence, if you qualify, the total change in the points throughout 2 games must be positive. If you fail to qualify, the total change must be negative.
> 2. Winning/drawing/losing the second leg game also matters. If you win the first game 4-0 and lose the second game 3-0, then anyway you must lose some points in second game, but the amount of losing points should not exceed the amount of point you've gain in the first game (because we must satisfy the condition 1).
> 3. The first leg should be considered as a standard game.

I thought several cases:

1) First Win, Second Win : Just apply the formula as usual. I see no reason in changing that.

2) First Win, Second Draw (Eventual win) : First you get point, and second you get or lose point. If your team are considered as very strong, then your team would lost some points in second game, but the amount of point loss must be less than the amount of point gain. In terms of mathematics, $\Delta P_1 > 0$ and $\Delta P_1 + \Delta P_2 > 0$.

3) First Win, Second Lose (Eventual Win, like 3-0 and 0-2, or away goal win) : $\Delta P_1 > 0$, $\Delta P_2 < 0$, $\Delta P_1 + \Delta P_2 > 0$.

4) First Win, Second Lose (Eventual Lose, like 3-0 and 0-4, or away goal lose) : $\Delta P_1 > 0$, $\Delta P_2 < 0$, $\Delta P_1 + \Delta P_2 < 0$.

5) First Draw, Second Win (Eventual Win) : $\Delta P_2 > 0$, $\Delta P_1 + \Delta P_2 > 0$.

6) First Draw, Second Draw (Eventual Win, like away goal or penalty shootouts after extra time) : $\Delta P_1 + \Delta P_2 > 0$.

Since the point system is zero-sum, these cases are all we need to consider.

I'm struggling on making ideas about how to revise the formula for case 2)~6). Any talk would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just for precisation/curiosity: the rating system should be spelled Elo (only first letter capitalized) as it was developed in the 1960s by statistician Arpad Elo with the purpose of rating chess players.

Comment: @AndreaMori Thanks, edited that.